# Not all code paths return a value in case of a recursive algorithm

Tags: c#

I've just designed a recursive algorithm and implemented in C# encountering `not all code paths return a value` error. Here is the code:

```
public List<List<Event>> CollectPaths(IEnumerable<string[]> transitions, State q_r, State q_s, List<State> Q_T, ref List<Event> tempPath)
        {
            if (!Q_T.Any())
            {
                pathCollection.Add(tempPath);
                return pathCollection;
            }

            else
            {
                List<State> Q_O = new List<State>();
                Q_O = Get_Q_O(q_r, transitions);

                State qq = new State("");

                foreach (State q in Q_O)
                {
                    List<Event> S_O = new List<Event>();
                    List<Event> S_OO = new List<Event>();
                    S_O = Get_S_O(q_r, q, transitions);
                    S_OO = Get_S_OO(q_r, q, S_O, transitions);

                    if (q.ID == q_s.ID)
                    {
                        tempPath.AddRange(S_O);
                        pathCollection.Add(tempPath);
                        Q_T.Remove(q);
                        if (!Q_T.Any())
                            return pathCollection;
                        else
                            continue; /////////////Note 1
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        foreach(Event sigma in S_O)
                        {
                            if (AFC_1(S_OO) ||
                             AFC_2(S_OO) ||
                             (AFC_3_1(S_OO, S_O) && AFC_3_2(GetC_S_OO(S_OO), GetU_S_OO(S_OO)))
                            )
                            {
                                tempPath.AddRange(S_O);
                                Q_T.Remove(q);
                                CollectPaths(transitions, q, q_s, Q_T, ref tempPath);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Q_T.Remove(q);
                                if (!Q_T.Any())
                                    return pathCollection;
                                else
                                    continue; /////////////Note 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

There are many conditional branches, and I've done my best to make algorithm return the `pathCollection`, finally.

Some Remarks:

`Note 1` and `Note 2`: the `continue` continues the `foreach` for the other values of `q`. Then, either it will get rid of the `if` and execute the `else`; or `Q_T` (a global variable which can be changed by all instantiations of the function) will become empty and `pathCollection` returns.

But I can't figure out what's wrong with this code!

Could you please give me some advice about it?

Comment: To answer this we need to ask ourselves: is every possible branch of the function going to return a value? The for loops aren't necessarily going to hit that if statement according to the compiler.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier: Yes. I've planned the processing to hit the mark, but seemingly there is a flaw that I can't find.

Comment: I don't think the issue is whether or not you have safeguarded the fact that it will hit the if statement, but rather the fact that the interpreter looks at this, sees that the returns are in if statements and NOT in the else statements, and therefor there is a possibility that it won't return a value.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that you'll always reach a `return` statement. (I don't know that either.) Just put some sort of `return` (or throw an exception) at the bottom of the function.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `Q_O` is empty?

Comment: @DourHighArch: It's impossible according to the algorithm's logic. Put differently, it never occurs. Shall I cover this case?

Comment: Your notes 1 and 2 are exactly where your problem with. If those continues are hit and continue to be hit until you run out of items to foreach then it will come out of the foreach having never returned anything. You need to put something after the foreach to cover that eventuality. The compiler can't look at the data you are providing so it can't establish that it will always hit one of the returns in the foreach. If you are sure that it should never reach the end of the foreach then you can throw an exception afterwards with a message indicating it should never be hit.

Comment: @Chris: "You need to put something after the foreach to cover that eventuality": You mean both foreach loops?

Comment: The outer foreach loop. Think of it more as putting in a throw exception as the last thing in the method. The error you are getting is with it reaching the end of the method without an exit point so if it hasn't returned before then you put in an exit point in the form of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are positive that the function is going to safely return a value, just add a return statement above your last bracket.

However, I would recommend trying to refactor your code to catch this sort of thing (adding exceptions, etc) to make sure this very confusing algorithm is operating correctly.

Comment: No, don't add a return statement. Otherwise if you get there then it will return something which would be nonsense. If it should never get there then throw an exception indicating that. That way in the exception situation that it does reach there you get an exception and are immediately told there is a problem with your logic. If you return something then... Well, what would you return that made sense?

Comment: That is what I meant by refactoring to catch this sort of thing. Extremely bad practice to add a return statement, I agree, nothing would make sense to return, I was just adding a direct solution to the issue. Editing my answer to fix my verbage.

Comment: You can simply return null... null is not nonsense. Null means there were no paths that satisfied the algorithm. Or you could throw an exception.

Comment: If that's what you mean by refactoring then I still disagree with how you've phrased your answer. You have said "Add a return statement" in the first paragraph and then your second seems to be saying "And now remove that return statement in favour of an exception." Why not just suggest an exception in the first place?